# I think my Bridge's foundation is too fragile

Tags: java, object-oriented, homework

I've just started a new class learning Java, and since it's been a long time since I've programmed in it I thought I'd put up my first project to get back in the swing of things.  Here is my first assignment:

> Welcome to the Bridge Crossing Problem. Person Pn can cross the bridge
>   in n minutes. Only one or two persons can cross at a time because it
>   is dark, and the flashlight must be taken on every crossing. When two
>   people cross, they travel at the speed of the slowest person. Devise a
>   sequence of crossings so that all four people get across the bridge in
>   no more than 17 minutes.

So I built a system of classes to handle all of this, these two here are the base two.  How can I improve this code?  Any new Java 8 features I'm not taking advantage of?

**Position.java**:

```
package bridge;

/**
 * An enumerated type whose values indicate sides of the bridge in the bridge problem.
 * Refer to these values using "<b>Position.EAST</b>" and "<b>Position.WEST</b>"
 */
public enum Position { EAST, WEST }
```

**BridgeState.java**:

```
package bridge;

/**
 * This class represents states of the Bridge Crossing problem.
 * It creates new bridge states, tests states for equality,
 * and produces string representations of them.
 * @author your name here
 */
public class BridgeState {

    private final Position p1Location;
    private final Position p2Location;
    private final Position p5Location;
    private final Position p10Location;
    private final Position flashLocation;
    private final int time;
    /**
     * Creates a new bridge state.  
     * Besides storing the positions of the persons and flashlight, a
     * bridge state should also store the time taken so far to cross in
     * integer minutes.
     * @param p1Position position of the person who can cross in 1 minute
     * @param p2Position position of the person who can cross in 2 minutes
     * @param flashlightPosition position of the flashlight
     * @param p5Position position of the person who can cross in 5 minutes
     * @param p10Position  position of the person who can cross in 10 minutes
     * @param timeSoFar time taken so far
     */
    public BridgeState(Position p1Position, 
                       Position p2Position, 
                       Position flashlightPosition, 
                       Position p5Position, 
                       Position p10Position,
                       int timeSoFar) 
    {
        p1Location = p1Position;
        p2Location = p2Position;
        p5Location = p5Position;
        p10Location = p10Position;
        flashLocation = flashlightPosition;
        time = timeSoFar;

    }

    /**
     * Tests this bridge state with another for equality.
     * Two bridge states are equal if the positions of the persons and 
     * flashlight in one state are matched by their positions in the other.
     * Note that the time taken to cross so far is not taken into account
     * when considering equality.
     * @param other the other bridge state to be tested against this one.
     * @return true if this state is equal to the other state, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean equals(BridgeState other) 
    {
        if (p1Location == other.p1Location 
         && p2Location == other.p2Location
         && p5Location == other.p5Location
         && p10Location == other.p10Location
         && flashLocation == other.flashLocation
         ) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a string representation of this state for display to the user
     * trying to solve the problem.
     * Note that the time so far to cross is part of the string representation.
     * @return the string representation of this state
     */
    public String toString() {
        String str = new String();
        str += String.format("%3s |   |%s\n", (p1Location == Position.WEST ? "P1" : ""), (p1Location == Position.EAST ? " P1" : ""));
        str += String.format("%3s |   |%s\n", (p2Location == Position.WEST ? "P2" : ""), (p2Location == Position.EAST ? " P2" : ""));
        str += String.format("%3s |===|%s\n", (flashLocation == Position.WEST ? "f" : ""), (flashLocation == Position.EAST ? " f" : ""));
        str += String.format("%3s |   |%s\n", (p5Location == Position.WEST ? "P5" : ""), (p5Location == Position.EAST ? " P5" : ""));
        str += String.format("%3s |   |%s\n", (p10Location == Position.WEST ? "P10" : ""), (p10Location == Position.EAST ? " P10" : ""));
        str += String.format("Time elapsed so far: %d minutes.\n", time);
        return str;
    }

    public Position getFlashlightPosition() 
    {
        return flashLocation;
    }

    public Position getP10Position() 
    {
        return p10Location;
    }

    public Position getP1Position() 
    {
        return p1Location;
    }

    public Position getP2Position() 
    {
        return p2Location;
    }

    public Position getP5Position() 
    {
        return p5Location;
    }

    public int getTimeSoFar() 
    {
        return time;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a few basic findings. I know you're mainly aiming at Java 8 features, but maybe I can follow up with more later on when I have more time. I think it might also be interesting to see how this `BridgeState` class is used later.

**Code Style**

- Your bracket positions are inconsistent. In some places you are
  putting them on the same line (`public String toString() {`), in some
  places you are putting them on the next line (`public Position getFlashlightPosition()`).
- Your field is e.g. named `p1Location`, but your getter is named
  `getP1Position` (same goes for the others). Usually getters are named after their corresponding fields (i.e. `getP1Location`).
- At first glance I'm not a fan of your `p1Location`, `p2Location`, etc variables. It might be more beautiful to use something like

  ```
  public class Person {
      int timeNeeded;
      Position position;
  }
  ```

  although I haven't thought about this in detail yet. On the one hand it makes your class more extensible, on the other hand the problem is quite well defined and unlikely to have a dynamic number of people.
- Why is the `flashlightPosition` interrupting the person locations (read as: why not `p1Position`, `p2Position`, `p5Position`, `p10Position`, `flashlighPosition`)?
- `String str = new String();` is creating a basically unused object. Just initialize `str` with your first content.
- You should tag your `toString` method with `@Override`.
- Your javadoc states that `BridgeState` "creates new bridge states", which I cannot see. I would assume more logic behind state creation than a mere constructor (although one can probably argue about that).
- Your `Position` enum is probably not useful outside a `BridgeState` context, so you might as well make it an inner class.

**Correctness**

- When overriding `equals` (even if slightly altered from the one in `Object`) also override `hashCode`. Always.
  Consider the following example (made up, but it's one of the simplest ways to see the issue and it's not completely unrealistic):

  ```
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;

  public class BridgeStateTest {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Map<BridgeState, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
          BridgeState bridgeState1 = new BridgeState(Position.EAST, Position.EAST,
                  Position.EAST, Position.EAST, Position.EAST, 0);
          BridgeState bridgeState2 = new BridgeState(Position.EAST, Position.EAST,
                  Position.EAST, Position.EAST, Position.EAST, 0);
          map.put(bridgeState1, "foo");
          System.out.println(bridgeState1.equals(bridgeState2)); // true
          System.out.println(map.containsKey(bridgeState2)); // false
      }
  }
  ```

  For more information see e.g. [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).
- Your `equals` method throws a `NullPointerException` for `bridgeState.equals(null)`. While you are not strictly overriding [`Object.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), you should try to follow the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) (or rename your method). I'd suggest to change the method parameter to *indeed* override the method from `Object`.

Other things: I like the immutability.

Comment: I plan on posting the rest of the classes related to the assignment (that depend on these base classes) some point later, thanks for the review!